# PHP PDO SQL Server Null result causes exception

Tags: php, sql-server, exception, pdo

I have a PDO class so I can easily switch between database types.

```
  //*** Function: createQuery, Purpose: Create the query object ***
  function createQuery($theQuery)
        {
        $theQuery = str_replace('`', "'", $theQuery);
        $this->query = $theQuery;
        $this->sth = $this->pdo->prepare($theQuery, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR 
        => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        }

  //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute the PDO ***                                                                    
  function query($paramArray = [], $column = null)
        {
        try
        {
        if(!empty($paramArray))
              foreach ($paramArray as $key => &$val)
                    { $this->sth->bindParam($key, $val);}
        $this->sth->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) { $this->error_catcher( $e->getMessage());}

        if($column != null)
              {
              $column = ($this->sth->columnCount() < $column) ? 0 : $column;
              return $this->sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $column );
              }
        else
              return $this->sth->fetchAll();
        }
```

and it all works spiffingly well.  However, sometimes, if the result is NULL the code throws an exception

here is a typical query to build a menu :

```
 SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT caption, id
 FROM dbo.com_menuitems
 WHERE (suite = 'chrimbotu') AND (parentid = 0) AND (enabled = 1) AND (id IN
    ( 
      SELECT parentid AS id FROM dbo.com_menuitems AS com_menuitems_1
      WHERE (suite = 'chrimbotu') AND (perms <= - 1)GROUP BY parentid
      HAVING (parentid > 0))
    )
 ORDER BY parentid, vieworder, caption
```

and i load the query (from another script) like this :

```
  function getTopLevel($mySQL)
  {
      $this->_myConn->createQuery($mySQL);
      $result = $this->_myConn->query() or die (DumpSQL($mySQL).__FUNCTION__ .' Query failed.');
      $this->_topLevel = $result[0]['perms'];
  }
```

If I run the query with no 'chrimbotu' in the database, SSMS says [NULL, NULL] my script carks and throws the helpful error "Query failed".

If I add 'chrimbotu' to the database, but give it a perms of 9, SSMS says [NULL, NULL]  but my script is happy.

Both queries return a NULL, but is one more "NULLER" than the other?

FYI: 0 is the lowest permission, < 0 is "everybody" stuff

Comment: what does "SSMS says [NULL, NULL]" mean? According to the posted code the `die()` depends on the result set (which btw is even requested when the query fails).

Comment: SSMS == SQL Server Management Studio.  When I run the query in SSMS it returns caption = NULL, id =NULL  I want the code to die if the query fails.  But the query is *not* failing, it is producing a valid result.  NULL is a valid value.  It's just when there is NOTHING the code fails, but when there is NOTHING FITS THE FILTER the code is happy.